# PHP mail not working on Plesk

Tags: sendmail, plesk, php-7.1

I have been using Plesk servers for months with no problems. Then I had this issue on my first Plesk server but I could fix it with the telephone support service, now I tried to call them to fix again but they have just told me that they can't solve it because I don't have support and they don't give any kind of information.
Php mail works only when is used with SMTP. The function [mail()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) just doesn't send, no errors displayed. Any clue is helpful since I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Hi, if you purchased Plesk license directly from Plesk company you can create a ticket to Plesk support, if you purchased license from some hosting provider you can contact this hosting provider and they can create a ticket to Plesk. 
What is Plesk and OS version ? Maybe Outgoing mail control is enabled, but sendmail is not allowed: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213907645

Comment: We are using Centos 7, that configuration was try by us but not working as well. Now we think that is SO problem. I will investigate it. Thanks